# The CSS all property working unexpectedly on iOS

Tags: css, safari

The unexpected behavior applies specifically to the `color` property: (AFAIK)

It looks like when an element has `all:inherit` (or `all: unset`) iOS **locks the color** of that element to it's inherited (or inital) value at all costs - against the cascading rules.

Given the following really simple markup

```
<div>Hi there</div>
```

with CSS:

```
body {
  color: red;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
div {
  all: inherit;
  color: green; 
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

**Snippet demo:** (open with iOS device such as iPhone / iPad to see the issue)

```css
body {
  color: red;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
div {
  all: inherit;
  color: green;
  border: 5px solid green; 

}
```

```html
<div>Hi there</div>
```

...I would expect the resulting color of both the text and the border of the `div` to be green (and this is in fact the result on Chrome and firefox) however on iOS (10.3+)* the resulting border color is green however the text color is red!

An even more bizarre iOS issue is that when an element has `all:inherit` (or unset) there seems to be no way to change the color of a **descendant** element!

**Snippet Demo:**

```css
body {
  color: red;
}
div {
  all: inherit;
}
.inner {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>Hi there <span><strong class="inner">inner element</strong></span></div>
```

...so in the above snippet iOS colors the inner element in red!

Note: [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-all) says that iOS safari supports the CSS `all` property as of version 9.3 and doesn't report any known issues.

... so: Is there a workaround for this in iOS?

Currently, because of this issue I don't see any way of using the `all` property!

---

I tested three iOS devices: iphone 6s running iOS 10.3, iphone 7 running iOS 11 and iPad running iOS 11.1

Comment: This affects Safari on both macOS and iOS.

Comment: Interestingly, if you remove the color from the border declaration (so it says border: 5px solid), Safari has no trouble applying the green color to the border.

Comment: @BoltClock - so for a minute I thought that I could somehow use `currentColor` as a workaround ... [but no success](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/KyYORq)

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer
[Why css "all: unset" works weirdly in Safari browser for MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248747/why-css-all-unset-works-weirdly-in-safari-browser-for-macos)

It seems that Safari override all color properties with webkit-text-fill-color.

So using webkit-text-fill-color yourself to fix the color is the workaround :)