# Why css "all: unset" works weirdly in Safari browser for MacOS?

Tags: html, css, safari, unset

So basically I made this situation, the parent has the css `all: unset`.

Then I notice when I use Safari(Version `12.1.1 (14607.2.6.1.1)`) all the children of it color only can be effected by `*` block, not even inline or `!important`.

But only `color` behaves that way, as you can see the `background-color` is using it's own property.

But it works fine in Chrome, is it a glitch in safari or I did something wrong? And how can I fix it in Safari?

```css
* {
  color: red;                   /* Text color is using this one */
  background-color: pink;
}

.Parent {
  all: unset;
}

.Child {
  color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;     /* Background color is using this one */
}
```

```html
<div class="Parent">
  <div class="Child">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

- Expected result(Chrome)
  [image]
- Wrong result(Safari `Version 12.1.1 (14607.2.6.1.1)`)
  [image]

Comment: Same thing happened to me but for text-decoration. Only occurred on iOS 15 or lower. Probably also caused by the same bug as https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=158782

It was fixed by using -webkit-text-decoration - so I guess probably this bug will happen any time you're using "all: unset;" and then setting a property that has a webkit equivalent. And can be fixed by specifically adding the webkit versions of things as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Safari uses the special property [`-webkit-text-fill-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color). If you use that, the color works:

```css
* {
  color: red;                   /* Text color is using this one */
  background-color: pink;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: red;
}

.Parent {
  all: unset;
}

.Child {
  color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;     /* Background color is using this one */
  -webkit-text-fill-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="Parent">
  <div class="Child">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

[@ Dan Fabulich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54829/dan-fabulich) commented the bug for this below:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=158782

Comment: Wow I didn’t know there’s a property for that and I thought `color` is for coloring texts, thanks a lot!

Comment: But it still makes no sense that the `color` property is not working :/

Comment: No problem! `color` is usually used for coloring texts, but Safari is one of the few browsers that also has `-webkit-text-fill-color` to override it. It causes a lot of issues unless you know about it.

Comment: This is a filed bug on Safari. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=158782

Comment: @DanFabulich Thanks. I added it to the answer

Comment: They fixed the bug in Safari Technology Preview 105. https://webkit.org/blog/10428/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-105/ It will presumably be fixed in Safari 13.2 and higher.